# I get 500 internal server error when I try to reach the website. I run nginx postgres and keycloak in docker container

Tags: node.js, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

500 internal server error

when checked the nginx container logs this is the error that was showing.

rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: x.x.x.x, server: *.domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "master.domain.com

In location /auth when mentioned localhost keycloak cannot be reached when localhost is replaced with ip in nginx config it works fine.

Below is the nginx config file

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name domain.com;
#root /usr/share/nginx/html;
root /home/admin/newprodle/frontend/build/;
index index.html;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server{
listen 443 ssl;
server_name *.domain.com domain.com;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/privkey.pem;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:MD5;
root /home/admin/newprodle/frontend/build;
# root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index /index.html;
client_max_body_size 10M;
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
location /auth {
proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
proxy_http_version 1.1;
}
location /api {
proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
proxy_http_version 1.1;
}
location \~ .(jpg|png|jpeg|gif|pdf|xlxs|xl|doc❘docx) {
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
root /home/admin/newprodle/backend/src/uploads;
}
location /socket.io {
proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
proxy_http_version 1.1;
}

}
```